# Function App calling Notification Hub with Android Topic / Tags

Tags: azure-mobile-services, servicebus

Does anyone know how to send topic or tag with Andorid payload? 
With Apns it's easy:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"msg","badge":1,"sound":"tap.aif","tag":"918928"}}
```

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The Android platform expects the payload in the form:

```
{"data":{"message":"test message"}}
```

We also could get more info about how to send notification hub from [Azure official tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-gcm-android-push-to-user-google-notification#sending-notifications-from-the-webapi-backend).
About how to bind notification hub to azure function please refer to this [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs#gcm-native-notifications-with-c-queue-triggers).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom.. I got that part... I've read documentation everywhere I could for days on how to pass the topic with the message. I can do it easily via Web.API and it's just I can't seem to find the answer on how to pass it using Azure Function App. 

Thanks again for answering...
-Brian